# using the visibility property for multiple usercontrol wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, visibility

I have a scenario where i need to display multiple usercontrols based on their visibility property and show next visible control when the next button is clicked. I have added all the usercontrols in a stackpanel which it seems to be not a great idea and i think it does affect the performance of the application. could some one help me guide what will be the best way define this scenario.

```
 <StackPanel Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Margin="4 4 28 0" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True">
                <Border BorderThickness="3" BorderBrush="LightGray" >
                    <StackPanel>
                    <controls:ICUC x:Name="ICU" BorderBrush="CadetBlue" Visibility="{Binding Visibilityicuc}"    ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Foreground="Black" VerticalAlignment="Center"  Height="210"  />
                        <controls:J1939 x:Name="J1939eng" BorderBrush="CadetBlue" Visibility="{Binding Visibilityj1939}"  ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Foreground="Black" VerticalAlignment="Center"  Height="210"  />
                    <controls:p_code x:Name="pcodengg" BorderBrush="CadetBlue" Visibility="{Binding Visibilitypcode}"   ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Foreground="Black" VerticalAlignment="Center"  Height="210"  />
                        <controls:Diagnostic_Developer x:Name="diagdev" BorderBrush="CadetBlue" Visibility="{Binding Visibilitysgdd}"   ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Foreground="Black" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="Auto" Width="Auto"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Border>
            </StackPanel>
```

Comment: What is the exact problem you are trying to solve? It sounds like there is no problem at all, you are only concerned about performance. Did you notice a performance problem?

Comment: Yes, when the page loads all this controls are loaded and their datacontext gets the data, i want to create a next button which when clicked it should check if the next controls visibilty is set to visible or collapsed and if visible it should show the next control.

Comment: Have you tried adding the control dynamically instead of switching visibility?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just recently implemented precisely the same thing at work. Here is an adapted version for your code, hope it's helpful.

ViewModel:

```
public class ExampleClass
{
    private int section { get; set; }

    public Visibility Visibilityicuc { get; set; } //presume first section
    public Visibility Visibilityj1939 { get; set; } //presume second section
    public Visibility Visibilitypcode { get; set; } //presume third section
    public Visibility Visibilitysgdd { get; set; } //presume fourth section

    public DelegateCommand NextButtonDelegateCommand { get; set; }

    public ExampleClass()
    {
        NextButtonDelegateCommand = new DelegateCommand(Next);
        section = 1; //indicates in first section
    }

    private void SetSectionVisibility(int currSection)
    {
        if (currSection == 1) // if first section
        {
            Visibilityicuc = Visibility.Visible; //section 1
            Visibilityj1939 = Visibility.Hidden;
            Visibilitypcode = Visibility.Hidden;
            Visibilitysgdd = Visibility.Hidden;
        }
        else if (currSection == 2)
        {
            Visibilityicuc = Visibility.Hidden;
            Visibilityj1939 = Visibility.Visible; //section 2
            Visibilitypcode = Visibility.Hidden;
            Visibilitysgdd = Visibility.Hidden;
        }
        else if (currSection == 3)
        {
            Visibilityicuc = Visibility.Hidden;
            Visibilityj1939 = Visibility.Hidden;
            Visibilitypcode = Visibility.Visible; //section 3
            Visibilitysgdd = Visibility.Hidden;
        }
        else if (section == 4)
        {
            Visibilityicuc = Visibility.Hidden;
            Visibilityj1939 = Visibility.Hidden;
            Visibilitypcode = Visibility.Hidden;
            Visibilitysgdd = Visibility.Visible; //section 4
        }
    }

    private void Next()
    {
        if (section == 1)
            SetSectionVisibility(2); //move to next section
        else if (section == 2)
            SetSectionVisibility(3);
        else if (section == 3)
            SetSectionVisibility(4);
        //else if (section == 4)
            //end! special event? unsure
    }
}
```

I would also do a few subtle updates to your current XAML code to ensure this works correctly!
That is, ensure your bindings are in this format:

```
Visibility="{Binding Visibilityicuc, Mode=TwoWay, Fallbackvalue=Visibility.Hidden}"
```

By setting the default state of the item, it will be invisible (obviously make section 1 Visibility.Visible, not hidden!). If you are familiar with PropertyChanged events too, I recommend you use them to notify your view when the visibility of a particular section has changed. If you are unfamiliar, comment back and I will give you an implemented example for your code.

Thanks! Hope this was helpful

Comment: Perfect, Thank You :)

Comment: My pleasure, glad it helped!

Comment: Hi, @PeripherySilence! Not OP here, but I am referring to your solution some years later, and have a follow up question! This code, would it account for changes made explicitily to the visibility of one of the controls after a function is executed? Say, I want to collapse the control for the `Visibilityicuc`, would explictily setting it's visibility to Hidden in the function trigger the correct changes?